# OnClientClick not triggering on first click on button after postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP button. On click of it I am opening a pop-up after doing some validations using JavaScript.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnHistory" runat="server" Text="History" Enabled="true" Width="100pt" OnClientClick="ShowHistoryPopup()" meta:resourcekey="btnHistory" OnInit="btnHistory_Init"/>

function ShowHistoryPopup() {

                var age = $get("<%= txtSomeTextBox.ClientID %>");
                var str = "";
                if (Validate(age)) {
                    str = 'ClService.aspx?id=' + 'Null,' + age.value;
                    window.open(str);
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

I have a radio button. Based on selected index I need to enable disable the History button. Radio button has 3 options and on 3rd option page postback happens. I need to keep the button enable on 1 st option only. I have implemented this logic with the help of Java Script and some code on OnPreRender event(for post back case).

Now the problem I am facing is, if I select option 1 or 2 and click History button, OnClientCLick event is triggering. But if I select option 3(postback) and then navigate back to option 1, onClientCLick is NOT triggering for the very first time. But on clicking the History button 2nd time its working fine. Anyone having suggestions or solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem I think what's happening is you are posting back after the History Button click which isn't what you want (as there's no click handler). Using this code works for me:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="Radio1" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="Radio1" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="Radio1" />

<asp:Button ID="btnHistory" runat="server" Text="History" Enabled="true" Width="100pt" OnClientClick="ShowHistoryPopup();return false;" meta:resourcekey="btnHistory" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowHistoryPopup() {
               alert("Here");
            }
    </script>
```

All I've added is the `return false;` after `ShowHistoryPopup();`

Also, I've used alert here for the purposes of demo, in reality we should really be using `console.log('Show my message');`